# Java Couting Charcters using methods

Tags: java

I am trying to get the first for loop into its own private method and i cant seem to get it without messing up to input. The goal is only to have the main method be used for calling methods and have all the actual calculations done in methods.

Any guidance would be appreciated

Here's part of my code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CountChars {
static int[] alphabetArray = new int[26];
public static void main(String[] args) {
     int linenum = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(input.hasNext()){
          String userInput =input.nextLine();
          String input1 = userInput.toLowerCase();
          for ( int i = 0; i < input1.length(); i++ ) {
             char ch=  input1.charAt(i);
             int value = (int) ch;
             if (value >= 97 && value <= 122){
             alphabetArray[ch-'a']++;
          }
        }
     int others= counts(++linenum, userInput);
    printLetterCounts();
    String yesorno= anyVowels(userInput);
    String VowCont= countVowels (userInput);
    int Contcount= countConsonants(0, userInput);
    zeroLetterCount();
    System.out.print(" others="+others); // ADDED THIS LINE
    System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation of this is also not correct / doesn't make any sense :

```
private static void zeroLetterCount(){
     for (int i=0;i<alphabetArray.length;i++)
          alphabetArray[i] = 0;
}
```

Change count method  :

```
private static int counts(int lineNum, String s){
     int count0 = s.length();
     int count1 = s.replaceAll("[^aeiou]","").length();
     int count2 = s.replaceAll("[^bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]","").length();
     int calc = count0-count1-count2;
     System.out.printf("Line %02d:", lineNum);
     return calc;
 }
```

Change you main to :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     int linenum = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(input.hasNext()){
          String userInput =input.nextLine();
          String input1 = userInput.toLowerCase();
          for ( int i = 0; i < input1.length(); i++ ) {
             char ch=  input1.charAt(i);
             int value = (int) ch;
             if (value >= 97 && value <= 122){
             alphabetArray[ch-'a']++;
          }
        }
     int others= counts(++linenum, userInput); // THIS LINE CHANGE AND MOVED UP.
    countAllChars();
    String yesorno= anyVowels(userInput);
    String VowCont= countVowels (userInput);
    int Contcount= countConsonants(0, userInput);
    zeroLetterCount();
    System.out.print(" others="+others); // ADDED THIS LINE
    System.out.println();    
   }
}
```

Count each char method :

```
private static void countAllChars() {
    for (int i = 0; i < alphabetArray.length; i++) {
        if(alphabetArray[i]>0) {
            char ch = (char) (i+97);
            System.out.print(ch +"="+alphabetArray[i]+ " ");
        }
    }
}
```

INPUT :

```
hevdhfewfewfe
hhwwrrr73##$6%&%7
```

OUTPUT:

```
Line 01:d=1 e=4 f=3 h=2 v=1 w=2 YES vowels=4 Consonants=9 others=0
Line 02:h=2 r=3 w=2 NO vowels=0 Consonants=7 others=10
```

Comment: Line number is still not increasing with each user input. I needs to go up by 1 each time

Comment: What if I needed to put the character counting portion and the printing of the character breakdown into its own method?

Comment: Im trying to get the very first for loop into its own method and cant get it without messing up my input. Any guidance for that?

Answer (score 0):

If you need your line-counter in a method, you could do:

```
   linenum = printLineCount(linenum);

[...]
   protected int printLineCount(int lineCount) {
     System.out.printf("Line %02d:", lineCount);
     return lineCount + 1;
   }
```

At the same time, your only line-feed `System.out.println()` is outside that while-loop. Should be within, so you create one line per line of input.

On second thought: Your desired output dictates you first process all input and only then create output. So maybe you should first stuff input lines into a List and operate on that to generate the output?